# Using one context menu strip with multiple grids

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I use multiple xtragrids on a  form and want to use a single context menu strip with a delete functions on these grids.I would like to handle the click event of the context menu:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView view = sender as GridView;
            {



            }
        }
```

tried this code,but for some reason i can not get the data from sender.Any chance of knowing which grid the menu was clicked on so i could delete the row from the clicked grid?

Comment: "Any chance of knowing which grid the menu was clicked on so i could delete the row from the clicked grid?" - Yes, but the code you have provided won't tell us - _or you_ - which one was clicked on.

Comment: It looks like that the `sender` is exactly `deleteToolStripMenuItem`, however it depends on the `event raising mechanism` implemented by the original code, you should perform some simple check by printing out the type of `sender` by `sender.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl` to access to the control popping up the `Context menu`, of course when you right-click on your grid, `SourceControl` will be your grid:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  GridView view = contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl as GridView;//Not sure if it's GridView or GridControl, you may want to try it yourself (I'm not familiar with DevExpress)
  //....
  //....
}
```